# Error in Site Stats of this site

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign

Here is a screenshot of the site stats for this site:

[image]

If there are only 1330 users, then how on earth can 1698 of them visit the site everyday?

Is this a bug?

Comment: What @iandotkelly says, this stat, far as I know, is actually pruned and rounded down from page views/visits.  Not related to user visitation stats in anyway other than the users themselves adding to it.

Answer (score 6):

People do not have to log in to the site (i.e. to become users) to view the site. Visitors per day probably uses various means to identify distinct visitors - ip addresses, user agents, maybe cookies (I don't know the details of exactly what they use).